# Show/Hide AcroFields in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following code:

```
PdfStamper pst = null;
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(GetTemplateBytes());
            pst = new PdfStamper(reader, Response.OutputStream);
            var acroFields = pst.AcroFields;

            pst.FormFlattening = true;
            pst.FreeTextFlattening = true;
            pst.SetFullCompression();

            SetFieldsInternal(acroFields);
            pst.Close();
        }

protected override void SetFieldsInternal(iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields acroFields)
{
    acroFields.SetFieldProperty("txtForOffer", "setflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT, null);
}
```

How do I **show / hide** the acrofields in the SetFieldsInternal function ?

The point is that the user may want to download 2 versions of the PDF, one with some text showing, one without text showing.

The template PDF is generated using OpenOffice. I just fill in the acrofields.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an AcroField as readonly like this:

```
form.setFieldProperty("companyFld", "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
```

It is "setfflags" BTW not "setflags"

EDIT: MY BAD!!!  You asked to make a field visible or not.  You would use the "setflags" argument in this case and you can pass any of the PdfAnnotation FLAGS_ constants to adjust visibility.

Comment: What did you try?  PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT will make it visible.  PDFAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN and FLAGS_INVISIBLE will both hide the field.